# View above DrawerLayout is not becoming visible even after .bringToFront and View.VISIBLE

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

Following is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:max="10000"
        android:maxHeight="15dip"
        android:minHeight="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Add content here -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_fragments_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_items_list"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

By default progress_layout visibility is GONE. Whenever user clicks on a menu item, I want to show the progress bar on top of(overlay) existing fragment and start the background operation. To show this layout currently I call following method:

```
public void showProgress(int progress){
    LinearLayout progressLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_progress_bar);
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    progressLayout.bringToFront();
    progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    LinearLayout dashboardLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_layout);
    dashboardLayout.requestLayout();
    dashboardLayout.invalidate();
}
```

But still I don't see my progress bar on top of my fragment.

Please let me know how can I get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file the `LinearLayout` with id: `progress_layout` is in gone mode. So you need add this line in `showProgress` method:

```
progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: No it doesn't work. I have already tried it. Actually there was typo in posting question. I edited my question. Instead of progressLayout, I typed progressBar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple solution is move progress bar to on top of your view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Add content here -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_fragments_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_items_list"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<!-- move your progress_layout to end of this xml, it will be on top of view --> 
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:max="10000"
        android:maxHeight="15dip"
        android:minHeight="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And now you only set visibility = VISIBLE when you want show it.

Comment: @ginahtran: this din't help me